# Unable to remove objects from a list in another object

Tags: python

Here is some test code to describe my problem.  I have created two classes as follows...

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(13):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

d = Deck()
d.cards.remove(Card(1, 1))
```

After the last remove command, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#111>", line 1, in <module>
    d.cards.remove(Card(1, 1))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring?  I can confirm the d object gets initialized with 52 total Card objects from (0, 0) to (3, 13).  Why does it not detect this with the remove module?  Furthermore, I can do the following commands after the initialization and it works with no problem.

```
d.cards.append(Card(1, 1))
d.cards.remove(Card(1, 1))
```

This adds and then remove the Card that was just added to the list, but it will not remove the card that was initialized with the same value.

Comment: Give your `Card` class a `__eq__` method.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't define when two `Card` instances are equal. Without such a definition, `list.remove()` can't find anything that is equal (`obj1 == obj2` is true). The default implementation for custom classes is to be equal only when the object is *identical* (the exact same object, `reference1 is reference2` is true).

Add an [`__eq__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to your class to define what equality means for `Card` instances.

For example, if two `Card` instances are equal if and when both `rank` and `suit` are equal, then implement that test:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Card):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit
```

Now `list.remove()` can find the first object that tests equal to the one you passed in to that method.

Note that:

```
d.cards.append(Card(1, 1))
d.cards.remove(Card(1, 1))
```

*can't work* without `__eq__` defined. That code creates two separate instances, and without a custom `__eq__` method two separate instances never test as equal.

You most likely did this instead:

```
card = Card(1, 1)
d.cards.append(card)
d.cards.remove(card)
```

because only then would the object test as equal; it is, after all, *the same object*.